# Rings of polynomial questions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Can someone please help me on figuring out how many distinct polynomials there are of degree at most 3 in the polynomial ring Z2[x], including the zero polynomial?

And how do I give two diﬀerent nontrivial elements in the kernel of the evaluation homomorphism ϕi: C[x] →C?

I'm at a standstill with these two. Not sure on how to tackle them. Thanks

Comment: For the second part, you need to find polynomials f(x) with complex coefficients such that f(i) = 0

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ is determined by it's $n+1$ coefficients where the coefficient of $x^n$ is non-zero. 
Thus there are $p-1$ choices for the leading coefficient and $p$ choices for the remaining coefficients. Hence there are $(p-1)p^n$ polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

Apply this for $p=2$ and $n=0,1,2,3$.

Comment: one more if we are including the zero polynomial

Comment: Oh, right, of course. For $n=0$ I have only counted $f(x)=1$.